# Inserting 2 items into a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert 2 items into a vector and I am having trouble understanding this line of code:

```
vector<pair<vertex *, double> > vec;
```

Can someone explain the meaning of this line? My thought process is that I have a vector that contains a class called `Pair` that takes in a pointer for a class called `vertex` and a value. How does this help me insert 2 items into a single cell in the vector? Any other suggestions on how I can insert 2 items into a single cell in the vector would be helpful.

Comment: you have a class called `Pair` that contains two objects and you can push that into a vector. How does this help you to push two objects into a vector? What exactly dont you understand?

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, i meant inserting 2 items into a single cell

Comment: @Soren the "i-th" position in the vector

Answer (score 4):

A `std::pair` is a class which is part of the Standard Template Library (STL) of C++. You can push an item into this vector as follows:

```
vec.push_back(std::make_pair(vert_ptr, value));
```

where `vert_ptr` is a pointer to an object of type `vertex` and `value` is a `double` variable.

Here, `std::make_pair` constructs a `std::pair` instance from the two parameters you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of your vector are pair objects. Each pair object contains a pointer to a vertex and a double.

So, if the 2 items you want to insert are a pointer to vertex and a double, you could create a `pair` from those and insert that into your vector.

The `pair` data type is defined in the Standard Library: `std::pair` The `vector` data type is in the Standard Library as `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The key piece of understanding here is that you cannot insert "two items" into a single "cell", and *you don't need to*.

You're trying to add *one* element. That element happens to be of type `std::pair`. A `std::pair` itself wraps two objects.

Once you grok that, you realise that you just handle the `std::pair` as you would any other vector element type, and you're laughing.

Comment: Interesting take on the "two inserts" -- I had not considered that :-)

Comment: so, in a sense `pair` be considered something as an 'object' that contains 2 items is that correct? And you're, in a sense, 'inserting' that 'pair object' into the vector?

Comment: @Bthegreatest 100%. That's exactly what you're doing. `std::pair<vertex*,  double>` is a class too. :)

Answer (score 0):

To insert into a vector, use `insert` instead of `push_back` -- insert takes a iterator as the first argument, so something like;

```
auto first = vec.begin();
vec.insert(first+3, std::make_pair(vert_ptr, value));
```

would insert at the 3rd element in the vector (assuming that there is that many already) -- fill in the blanks for error handling and other edge cases.

Note: that `vector` may not be the best structure to use if you have many inserts